# Why is this select so slow (SqlServer)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

We have 3 nested selects that are each creating temporary table. The outer two go very fast. But the inner one (below takes about 1/4 second sometimes to execute. It's creating a table with 7 rows, each holding a date:

```
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime
select @StartDate = cast(@Weeks_Loop_TheDate as date),  @EndDate = cast((@Weeks_Loop_TheDate + 6) as date)

declare @temp3  table
(
TheDate datetime
)
while (@StartDate<=@EndDate)
begin
insert into @temp3
values (@StartDate )
select @StartDate=DATEADD(dd,1,@StartDate)
end
select * from @temp3
```

The params are set with a DateTime variable so the cast shouldn't be significant. And the populating should be trivial and fast. So any ideas why it's slow?

And is there a better way to do this? We need to get back a result set that is 7 dates in this range.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work? Loops/cursors are slow in SQL Server compared to set operations.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2017-05-03';

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, RowNr, @StartDate)
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 AS RowNr FROM sys.objects) AS T
WHERE T.RowNr < 7;
```

Subquery will generate a sequence of numbers from 0 to n (amount of objects you have in database, it's always going to be more than 7, and if not, you can just `CROSS JOIN` inside).

Then just use `DATEADD` to add these generated numbers.
And finally limit amount of days you want to add in your `WHERE` clause.

And if you're going to use this quite often, you can wrap it up in a Inline Table-Valued Function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateTable (
  @p1 DATE,
  @p2 INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, RowNr, @p1) AS TheDate
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 AS RowNr FROM sys.objects) AS T
    WHERE T.RowNr < @p2;
GO
```

And then query it like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DateTable ('2017-05-03', 7);
```

Result in both cases:

```
+------------+
|  TheDate   |
+------------+
| 2017-05-03 |
| 2017-05-04 |
| 2017-05-05 |
| 2017-05-06 |
| 2017-05-07 |
| 2017-05-08 |
| 2017-05-09 |
+------------+
```

Yet another useful tool is a `Numbers` table. It can be created just like that (source: http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) :

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers
(
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
        WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
)

INSERT INTO Numbers
SELECT
    (a.Number * 256) + b.Number AS Number
FROM 
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE 
            type = 'P'
            AND number <= 255
    ) a (Number),
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE 
            type = 'P'
            AND number <= 255
    ) b (Number)
GO
```

Then you would not have to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and your function could be as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DateTable (
  @p1 DATE,
  @p2 INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Number, @p1) AS TheDate
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE Number < @p2;
GO
```

This is going to work like a charm and `Numbers` table could be reused in many other scenarios where you need a sequence of numbers to do some sort of calculations.

Comment: You call this a "set operation" but isn't it actually a select? One that builds the result set instead of pulling data from the DB but still just a select? Or is that the definition of a set operation?

Comment: @DavidThielen Perhaps I misphrased what I wanted to say. The idea is - loops/cursors are generally performing bad in SQL Server and are not recommended, there are cases when it's okay to use them, but It's recommended to encapsulate your whole logic within a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thank you for explaining further. Your solution works great but I want to also fully understand so I can do this going forward. I will endeavor to avoid loops as much as possible (I'm a programmer and in my world loops are great). Thank you.

Comment: @DavidThielen In programming loops are a norm and there's nothing wrong with it. Loops also can be used in databases efficiently to reduce batch sizes for large operations or execute stored procedures for multiple parameters. There are use cases :)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take more than a millisecond to run your script. There must be a server issue that requires investigation.

That said, this operation can be done as a more efficient set-based operation instead of looping. The example below uses a CTE to generate the number sequence.  A utility numbers table facilitates set-based processing like this so I suggest you create a permanent table with a sequence of numbers (with number as the primary key) to improve performance further.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = @Weeks_Loop_TheDate;
WITH numbers(n) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS a(b)
    )
SELECT DATEADD(day, n, @StartDate)
FROM numbers
ORDER BY n;
```

Comment: If you're hardcoding values, doesn't it make more sense just to write all of 7 values and remove `ROW_NUMBER()`? Just like that: `SELECT b FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) AS a(b)`

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, the hard-coded list of numbers could be used for this particular use case but this CTE approach can be extended for much larger sets. For example, one could use a CTE with the values and another CTE to cross join with the values as many times as needed to generate a sequence with ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: You're right, I thought you've given a solution for this specific case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a variable such as @temp use a temp table (#) instead. The query analyser doesn't do optimizing well when using @temp.

Comment: What's the difference? From Googling it looks like @tempName and #tempName are the same thing.

Comment: The Optimizer cannot not sniff the “Estimated Number of Rows”  because the entire batch query populates the variable table. Resulting in the estimated number of rows being always 1.